# Git won't pick up changes to certain files

Tags: php, git, github

Have a very odd and annoying issue with Git/GitHub.

In a certain branch, any file that has the path as `/views/admin/index.php`, `/views/teacher/index.php`, `/views/parents/index.php`, `/views/student/index.php` won't detect any changes to the files no matter what. Deleting the file, removing all the code, or just making a small edit isn't picked up at all.

We are using Codeigniter v2.2.0 as the framework, if that is of any use.

This is happening through any folder with a file structure like that.

Have tried multiple different software including the GitHub native app and Sourcetree.

There is another branch we have that works fine.

Tried cloning the branch with the issue but it still has the problems on the new branch.

Any ideas that could help would be great :)

Comment: Maybe the file is on an ignore list?

Comment: @halcyon Yep, it was. Massive facepalm moment there. Needed to do /index.php as I want to ignore the index.php from the main directory only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Massive facepalm moment.

I had index.php in the .gitignore, I needed to have /index.php to ignore only the index.php in the main directory.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have a file which seems to be ignore, you quickly can check that with [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/yourFile
```

That will help list the exact `.gitignore` referencing that file.

Comment: This is amazing. They really need to update the [Linux Kernel version of the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html), because this command doesn't even show up there.

Comment: @Cupcake It has been a couple of years (since the August 2011 attack: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel.org) that kernel.org is *no longer* the reference in term of git documentation. http://git-scm.com/docs/ is since then.

Comment: @Cupcake congrats on your gold badge for the git tag by the way. Well deserved! (http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2214236#2214236)

Comment: Ah, the gold badge, thank you, I'm so excited to finally have one! As for the attack on kernel, that makes sense, I understand now. That's a big shame, because the git-scm docs make it quite a bit harder to find lesser-known commands. Maybe I'll send them some pull requests or start hosting my own fork someday.

Comment: I'm not sure if you knew about this already, but [Jan Krüger](http://jk.gs/) actually already maintains his own [fork of the git documentation](http://jk.gs/git.html). I think I might start linking to that more often, to supplement the Git SCM versions, since it doesn't try to simplify anything.

Comment: @Cupcake I didn't know that. I will still use git-scm for all my documentation link though.

Answer (score 0):

If your using SourceTree as you mentioned, change the File Status combo from the Working Copy view to "Show Ignored". 
It doesn't display ignored or untracked in "Show All".